# Slack: Can I use Python to post as a specific USER on slack?

Tags: python, slack

All the libraries I find need some sort of administrator intervention and I am just a user who wants to automate some tasks for myself...

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can I... Please. 

Comment: Yes I am sure you can. But provide code on what you have tried so far. Give examples of task. Which administrator are you referring to?